# Singular or Plural (the evening(s))

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Which one is correct? Are both of them correct?

- I feel more energetic in the evening.
- I feel more energetic in the evening**s**.

Comment: The first is more idiomatic, with more usage – see [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+evening%2Cin+the+evenings&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @WeatherVane beware ngrams bearing false comparisons!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are idiomatic, but may have different implications. You are certainly more likely to hear "*in the evening*" but that doesn't mean you should never use the alternative.

"In the evening" has the broadest possible application. It means *every* evening. "*I have more energy in the evening*" would be a blanket statement that you feel more energetic at that time of day, compared to other times.

When we say "*the evenings*", it implies a more limited application - a set of evenings that you can count, in a particular time period, or in specific circumstances. For example, "*I like summer because the evenings are lighter*".